# VBA Excel - copy cell values and paste value in between characters of another cell

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I have a cell with value 11 and i want to copy this value and paste it in another cell (of another sheet) between characters "" or at the end of the sentence within the cell.

i.e.

the value ***11*** is in cell A1 and i want to paste it in sheet 2 cell A4 in the sentence : *modify frequency* "***11***".

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You need to at least show us some code that you have tried first.

Comment: the code i have is what i got from the record macro. in that scenario i was explicitly selecting the value and pasting it were i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub findandreplace()
    Dim string1 As String
    Dim string2 As String
    Dim string3 As String

    string1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Value
    string2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a4").Value
    string3 = Replace(string2, " ", string1)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a4").Value = string3

    Debug.Print ; string1
    Debug.Print ; string2
    Debug.Print ; string3
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Doug for your effort. Sorry for my ignorance but I am a starter in VBA, so i cannot understand exactly what are trying to say. I want to copy any value from A1 and paste it between " " in another sheet in cell A4.

Comment: I didnt know you wanted a VBA answer. trhis was just a simple formula. What kind of answer would you like? VBA or formula? Either way I'll need to adjust the answer to fit the other worksheet part.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I didn't use the exact code but something similar.

Comment: If this helped at all feel free to mark as answer :)